# Facebook request after app enter foreground

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-login

I have a problem with the Facebook SDK in iOS. Everything works perfectly but I have a problem with the login flow. When the user hits the "log into Facebook" button he gets directed to Facebook to allow my app to get permissions. That's fine. But when iOS is changing from the browser to my app and trying to make a request I get this error message:

```
FBSDKLog: Error for request to endpoint 'search?q=concert&type=event&limit=10': An open FBSession must be specified for calls to this endpoint.
```

When I'm closing the app and start it again and go and execute my request it works without error. I get my reqeust. That´s my code I know its not very neat.

ViewdidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidEnterForeground:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];

//Some other Code



if ([[FBSession activeSession]state])
{
    NSLog(@"User is logged in");
    [loginView setHidden:TRUE];


} else {
    // try to open session with existing valid token
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            @"user_events",
                            nil];
    FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
    if([FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO]) {

    } else {
        NSLog(@"User is logged out");

        //Create the FB Login-Button
        loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:@[@"user_events"]];
        // Align the button in the center horizontally
        loginView.frame = CGRectOffset(loginView.frame, (self.view.center.x - (loginView.frame.size.width / 2)), 200);

        [self.view addSubview:loginView];


    }
}

[self getEvents];

}
```

getEvents:

```
-(void)getEvents{
//Get General Events



[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"search?q=concert&type=event&limit=10"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {


                          if (!error) {
                                    //Some Code

                          else {
                              // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                              // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors

                          }

                      }];


   }
```

appDidEnterForeground

```
- (void)appDidEnterForeground:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSLog(@"App did enter forground again.");


[self viewDidLoad];
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, well I solved my own problem: I read through the docs again extremely carefully did everything again, added this to my delegate:

```
   // Whenever a person opens the app, check for a cached session
if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {

    // If there's one, just open the session silently, without showing the user the login UI
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
                                       allowLoginUI:NO
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                      // Handler for session state changes
                                      // This method will be called EACH time the session state changes,
                                      // also for intermediate states and NOT just when the session open
                                      [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                  }];



}

}



// This method will handle ALL the session state changes in the app


-(void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session state:(FBSessionState) state error:  (NSError *)error
   {
       // If the session was opened successfully
  // customize your code...

   }
```

and then I´m executing my method, which contains my request like this

```
// Logged-in user experience
```

- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {
    NSLog(@"You're logged in. (Method: loginviewshowingloggedinuser");

```
//If the User is logged in we can fetch the events
[self getEvents];
```

}